# Integrate Office-365-SDK-for-iOS

Tags: ios, azure, xcode6, office365

I am creating an iOS application in which I am integrating `Office-365-SDK-for-iOS` for import contacts from outlook365.I am successfully able to authenticate with Microsoft Azure. But when I am fetching user and user's contacts then following error is coming-

```
Error Domain=Error in the Request Code=401 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Error in the Request error 401.)
```

Here is my code for authentication and get client

```
//Acquire access and refresh tokens from Azure AD for the user.
-(void)acquireAuthTokenWithResourceId:(NSString *)resourceId completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL authenticated))completionBlock
{
    ADAuthenticationError *error;
    self.authContext = [ADAuthenticationContext authenticationContextWithAuthority:OutlookAuthority error:&error];
    [self.authContext acquireTokenWithResource:OutlookRsourceId
                                      clientId:OutlookClientId
                                   redirectUri:[NSURL URLWithString:OutlookRedirectUrl]
                               completionBlock:^(ADAuthenticationResult *result)
    {
                                   if (AD_SUCCEEDED != result.status)
                                   {
                                       completionBlock(NO);
                                   }
                                   else
                                   {
                                       NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                                       [userDefaults setObject:result.tokenCacheStoreItem.userInformation.userId
                                                        forKey:@"LogInUser"];
                                       [userDefaults synchronize];


                                       self.dependencyResolver = [[ADALDependencyResolver alloc] initWithContext:self.authContext
                                                                                                      resourceId:OutlookRsourceId
                                                                                                        clientId:OutlookClientId
                                                                                                     redirectUri:[NSURL URLWithString:OutlookRedirectUrl]];
                                       completionBlock(YES);
                                   }
                               }];
}



- (void) getClient:(void (^) (MSOutlookServicesClient *))callback
{

    OutlookAuthManager* authenticationController = [OutlookAuthManager sharedInstance];

    [authenticationController acquireAuthTokenWithResourceId:OutlookRsourceId completionHandler:^(BOOL authenticated)
    {

        if (authenticated)
        {
            callback([[MSOutlookServicesClient alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0" dependencyResolver:[authenticationController dependencyResolver]]);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Error in authentication");
        }
    }];
}
```

And following I am getting user-

```
[[OutlookAuthManager sharedInstance] getClient:^(MSOutlookServicesClient *client)
     {
         NSURLSessionTask* task = [[client getMe] readWithCallback:^(MSOutlookServicesUser *user, NSError *error)
                                   {
                                       if(error == nil)
                                       {
                                           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                                                          ^{
                                                              NSLog(@"------>%@",user.DisplayName);
                                                              NSLog(@"------>%@",user.Alias);
                                                              NSLog(@"------>%@",user.Id);
                                                              NSLog(@"------>%@",user.MailboxGuid);

                                                          });
                                       }
                                       else
                                       {

                                           [client.resolver.logger logMessage:error.description withLevel:LOG_LEVEL_ERROR];
                                       }
                                   }];

         [task resume];
     }];
```

But That error is coming here.
Please help me
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by [validating your access token](https://github.com/jasonjoh/office365-azure-guides/blob/master/ValidatingYourToken.md). Since it's a 401 it's likely a problem there.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can you let me know where I will give the permission for office365 exchange online. I don't have this type of permission. I only have Office 365 unified API(Preview) in this category.

Comment: Ravi, I answered on your other thread. My guess is that your Office 365 subscription doesn't include Exchange Online. Can you logon to Outlook Web App with your account? https://outlook.office365.com

Comment: Yes I have trial subscription which I am using.So this is the reason?